# Is there a way to switch between 2 values in an array for a tkinter label?

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to have a way to change the value of a label from Male to Female and vise versa, the error i keep getting is thatx is referenced before assignment

```
from tkinter import *
global x
x = 0
gender = ["Boy","Girl"]
ws = Tk()
ws.title('Python Guides')  
ws.geometry("400x300")
Label = Label(ws,text = f'Sex --> {gender[x]}')
Label.pack()
def change():
    x = x + 1
    q = x%2
    print(x)
    print(q)
    Label.config(text = f'Sex --> {gender[q]}') 

idk = Button(ws, text= "change", command= lambda:(change()))
idk.pack()
ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to declare `x` as global variable inside `change()`, otherwise it is treated as local variable and raise the exception because `x` is not defined before the line `x = x + 1`.  Note that the line `global x` at the beginning is useless and not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @acw1668 i wasn't expecting it to be that easy

Comment: `command=lambda:(change())` should be just `command=change`. That said, all this can be written way better

Comment: And don't use `Label` as name (now you shadow the `tkinter.Label` widget (due to the star import)

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not declare `x` as global variable inside `change()`, it will be treated as local variable.  So the line `x = x + 1` will raise the exception because local variable `x` is not defined before that line.

Just add `global x` at the beginning of `change()`:

```py
def change():
    global x
    x = x + 1
    ...
```

Note that `global x` at the beginning of your code is useless and not necessary because variable defined there is already a global variable.

You can get rid of using of global variable by declaring the gender list as a *cycle* list and use `next()` to get the next item in the list:

```py
from itertools import cycle
import tkinter as tk

# create a cycle list
gender = cycle(["Boy", "Girl"])

ws = tk.Tk()
ws.title('Python Guides')
ws.geometry("400x300")

# use next(gender) to get the next item in gender list
label = tk.Label(ws, text=f'Sex --> {next(gender)}')
label.pack()

def change():
    label.config(text=f'Sex --> {next(gender)}')

idk = tk.Button(ws, text="change", command=change)
idk.pack()

ws.mainloop()
```